# Struggling with DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an html table in my .aspx page which looks as follows:

```
  <table id="quotationsListTable" class="quoteTbl" width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>REF</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Arrival</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Departure</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Curr</th>
    <th>Sale</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td><input type="text" style="width: 50px" /> </td>
    <td><input type="text" style="width: 150px"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" style="width: 50px"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" style="width: 50px"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" style="width: 50px"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" style="width: 50px"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" style="width: 50px"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" style="width: 50px"/> </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

I also have a javascript function for deleting all the rows in my table, calling my by element ID "quotationsListTable".

The javascript function which stays in a separate .js file is a follows:

```
deleteAllrows('quotationsListTable');

function deleteAllrows(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementByID(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;


        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

The problem at hand is that my js function cannot retrieve the table by id, the error message that is thrown is 'undefined'.

Comment: Don't use `alert()` to debug; remove the try..catch completely and look in the [JavaScript error console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: To delete all rows you actually can just set its innerHTML = "";

Answer (score 3):

It's `document.getElementById` note the small `d`

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you include the jquery library and remove the rows with single line .. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SamirAdel/DyXHt/

```
deleteAllrows('quotationsListTable');

function deleteAllrows(tableID) {
   $("#"+tableID+"tr:gt(0)").remove()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your function after the page content is ready.
And please, change your "getElementByID" to "getElementById", D um lowercase.
Try to use jQuery, is an easy way.

See:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $().ready(function(){                
    deleteAllrows();

    function deleteAllrows() {
      try {
          var table = document.getElementById('quotationsListTable');
          alert(table);
          var rowCount = table.rows.length;

          for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
              var row = table.rows[i];
              var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
              table.deleteRow(i);
              rowCount--;
              i--;


          }
      } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
      }
    }        
  });
</script>
```